# c# string Compare

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create list filter in .net MVC4 C#.
I have ajax query that sends string to controller and according to matches in database it returns number of records.

So when the `String` is `IsNullOrEmpty()` and `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` it brings me fine result.
I have problem in matching values now.

Although it seemed me easy so i tried-

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SearchAccountHead(string accountHead)
{
    var students = from s in db.LedgerTables
                    select s;
    List<LedgerModel> ledge = null;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountHead)) 
    {
                    //Returns non-empty records
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountHead) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountHead))
    {

        //Checks whether string is null or containing whitespace
        //And returns filtered result
    }


    return PartialView(ledge);

}
```

Now if I have string that doesn't match with string I have been using in controller then I tried mapping it-

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountHead) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountHead) && !String.Compare(accountHead))

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(accountHead) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountHead) && !String.Compare(AccountHead,ledge.AccountHead))
```

But in both cases it didn't work.

How can I get into second method when string doesn't match?

Comment: `!String.Compare(AccountHead)` won't compile

Comment: Also "in case A and in case B do this" really means "if A or (if) B" and is written in C# as `if (A || B) { DoThis(); }

Comment: `String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)` is the same as `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)`. I'd recommend the latter, for succinctness.

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply `string.Compare` with `!`, since `string.Compare` would return an integer value. If you are comparing string for equality then its better if you use [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx), it also has an overload which does case insensitive comparison.

You can have the check like:

```
   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountHead) && 
                !String.Equals(AccountHead, ledge.AccountHead,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

As a side note you can remove

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(AccountHead) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AccountHead))
```

and just use

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AccountHead))
```

since `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` checks for empty strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Equals()` and pass it an option for comparison logic.  Something like this:

```
AccountHead.Equals(ledge.AccountHead, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

This will compare `AccountHead` and `ledge.AccountHead` in a case-insensitive manner using invariant culture rules.  There are [additional options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.StringComparer_properties.aspx) to choose from as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06.aspx) to do the same as `String.Equals`, however, it's a bit less succinct e.g.

```
String.Compare(AccountHead, ledge.AccountHead, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <> 0
```

Here's the shorter way...

```
!AccountHead.Equals(ledge.AccountHead, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I can't see any justification for it. +1 from me :)

Comment: string.Compare returns `int`, having `!` won't compile

Comment: @habib I had copied/pasted from the OPs code to demonstrate the extra parameter. Updated.

Comment: @James, I have removed the downvote, but its not a good idea to compare string for equality using `string.Compare`, string.Compare is used more for ordering.

Comment: @Habib that's true, the example I posted would be doing a culture-sensitive comparison. I have updated for a more robust check (similar to `Equals`). Obviously `Equals` is a more succinct way of doing it however I will leave it up there for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple and write something like this !(accountHead == ledge.AccountHead).
You don't need comparison as i see, but to check if strings are equal or not. Usually Equals is the best way to do that, but "==" does semantic and object.ReferenceEquals -- referential comparison. So i would go with that one.
Hope this helps